# How to increase the HQL performance

Tags: hql, hue

I have a following query and it takes 12 hours to execute in HUE. I would like to increase the performance of the query. Let me know what changes I can implement in the query to increase the performance in HUE environment

```
   SELECT ordernum, 
       Min(distance) mindist, 
       Min(CASE 
             WHEN type_name = 'T' 
                   OR ( type_name = 'I' 
                        AND item LIKE '%D%' ) THEN distance 
             ELSE 9999999 
           END)      min_t, 
       Min(CASE 
             WHEN type_name = 'A' THEN distance 
             ELSE 9999999 
           END)      min_a 
FROM   (SELECT a.ordernum, 
               b.id, 
               b.type_name, 
               b.item, 
               Round(Least(Sqrt(Pow(b.sty-a.nrthng, 2) 
                                + Pow(b.stx-a.estng, 2)), 
                     Sqrt(Pow(b.endy-a.nrthng, 2) 
                          + Pow(b.endx-a.estng, 2)))) 
               distance 
        FROM   temp_b a, 
               min_b1 b 
        WHERE  ( ( b.stx BETWEEN ( a.estng - 1000 ) AND ( a.estng + 1000 ) 
                   AND b.sty BETWEEN ( a.nrthng - 1000 ) AND 
                 ( a.nthing + 1000 ) ) 
                  OR ( b.endx BETWEEN ( a.estng - 1000 ) AND ( a.esng + 1000 ) 
                       AND b.endy BETWEEN ( a.nrthng - 1000 ) AND 
               ( a.nrthng + 1000 ) ) )) a 
GROUP  BY ordernum
```

Comment: Please format the query to increase it's readabilty.

Answer (score 0):

My concers are about your query join condition. 
As I see, you have tables *a* and *b*. Are there any key fields so tables could be matched? I mean, field *f1* from the table *a* has the same meaning as field *f2* from table *b* so they could be joined.
You could also create temporary table containing information from both tables to remove overhead for network communication and data transfer as I believe your hadoop cluster contains more than single node.